# Flashing blue dot on Google Map

Tags: google

I have an iphone 5S.  Sometimes when I use the Google map and enter a destination, my current location is a flashing blue dot which is very convenient.  Lately, the blue dot has been replaced with an arrow which is not as convenient.  How do I get my map to permanently show the flashing blue dot?

Answer (score 2):

The arrow is your current location, except that it also represents your current location *and* orientation **in navigation mode**.

Google Maps automatically switches between the blue dot that represents your current location to an arrow in a circle when you are using the app for navigation, as you can see in the following screenshots (surroundings obscured for general privacy):

---

Regular (non-navigation) mode, with blue dot representing current location
[image: blue dot]

Navigation mode, with arrow representing current location
[image: arrow]

---

As you can see, these are the defaults and I doubt they can be changed. You might just want to ensure that you aren't currently navigating anywhere (exit by tapping the 'X' at the bottom left corner) and your current location indicator should return to its usual blue dot self.